# Is there a way to convert a Serde Map into a Value?

Tags: rust, serde

As per the Serde specification, an `Object` / `Map<String, Value>` is a `Value`:

```
pub enum Value {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    Number(Number),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Value>),
    Object(Map<String, Value>),
}
```

Yet when I compile this code:

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_json;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Wrapper {
    ok: bool,
    data: Option<serde_json::Value>,
}

impl Wrapper {
    fn ok() -> Wrapper {
        Wrapper {
            ok: true,
            data: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn data(&mut self, data: serde_json::Value) -> &mut Wrapper {
        self.data = Some(data);
        self
    }

    pub fn finalize(self) -> Wrapper {
        self
    }
}

trait IsValidWrapper {
    fn is_valid_wrapper(&self) -> bool;
}

impl IsValidWrapper for serde_json::Map<std::string::String, serde_json::Value> {
    fn is_valid_wrapper(&self) -> bool {
        self["ok"].as_bool().unwrap_or(false)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let json = json!({
          "name": "John Doe",
          "age": 43,
          "phones": [
            "+44 1234567",
            "+44 2345678"
          ]
        });

    let converted_json: Wrapper = json
        .as_object()
        .map_or_else(
            || Err(json),
            |obj| {
                if obj.is_valid_wrapper() {
                    Ok(Wrapper::ok().data(obj["data"].clone()).finalize())
                } else {
                    Err(*obj as serde_json::Value)
                }
            },
        )
        .unwrap_or_else(|data| Wrapper::ok().data(data.clone()).finalize());
    println!(
        "org json = {:?} => converted json = {:?}",
        json, converted_json
    );
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `serde_json::Map<std::string::String, serde_json::Value>` as `serde_json::Value`
  --> src/main.rs:60:25
   |
60 |                     Err(*obj as serde_json::Value)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an `as` expression can only be used to convert between primitive types. Consider using the `From` trait
```

Is there a way to downcast a `Map` into a `Value`?

Comment: The `Map` is not  a `Value`, have you tried `Err(Value::Object(obj))`?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I edited my initial post as asked

Comment: @tafia seems to work. I got some more compiler error re moves and borrows which I will look into but at least that compiler issue is gone. Indeed a Map is not a Value but a Value::Object; thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> an `Object` / `Map<String, Value>` is a `Value`

No, it is not. `Value` is a type. `Map<String, Value>` is a type. `Value::Object` is an *enum variant*, which is not a separate type. In this case, `Value::Object` holds another value of type `Map<String, Value>`. You have to wrap the value in the variant to convert the type:

```
Err(serde_json::Value::Object(obj))
```

This will lead you to the problem:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:57:55
   |
57 |                         Err(serde_json::Value::Object(obj))
   |                                                       ^^^ expected struct `serde_json::Map`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `serde_json::Map<std::string::String, serde_json::Value>`
              found type `&serde_json::Map<std::string::String, serde_json::Value>`
```

`as_object` returns a reference to the contained object (if it's present), not the value itself. You will need to `match` on it for now:

```
let converted_json = match json {
    serde_json::Value::Object(obj) => {}
    _ => {}
};
```

Something like this:

```
let converted_json = match json {
    serde_json::Value::Object(obj) => {
        if obj.is_valid_wrapper() {
            let mut w = Wrapper::ok();
            w.data(obj["data"].clone());
            Ok(w.finalize())
        } else {
            Err(serde_json::Value::Object(obj))
        }
    }
    other => Err(other),
};
```

Answer (score 0):

simply

```
let your_map = serde_json::Map::new();
// ...
Value::from(your_map);
```